# error in getting avro string

Tags: c, serialization, avro

I am trying to do a simple string setter getter program using avro-c.

My code is :

```
avro_value_t frame_value;
avro_schema_t frame_schema = avro_schema_string();
avro_value_iface_t *frame_iface = avro_generic_class_from_schema(frame_schema);
avro_generic_value_new(frame_iface, &frame_value);

char *name;
int size;

avro_value_set_string(&frame_value,"hello");
avro_value_get_string(&frame_value,name,&size);
printf("\nname is %s",name);
printf("\nsize is %d",size);
```

but it outputs a null string although size is correct which is 6 including null character. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which warnings did your compiler print? And what did you try to silence them?

Comment: Removing all warnings worked.size should be of type size_t . I thought int can be casted to size_t.

Comment: `int` and `size_t` may have different size. There might be a reason why `size_t` exists. ;) And your compiler did not scream badly about wrong type for `name`? Besides the other flaws shown in AndreKampling's answer which are not that easy to fine. If your compiler provides a hint, listen!

Answer (score 0):

It must be the following, note `&name` instead of `name`:

```
avro_value_get_string(&frame_value, &name, &size);
```

as the function expects a double pointer to constant character. It's necessary to set the pointer under the hood to the internal character array that was set by the setter.

See [here in the API documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/c/):

> ```
> int avro_value_get_string(const avro_value_t *value,
>                           const char **dest, size_t *size);
> ```

Also make your `name` pointer pointing to constant character and your `size` being a `size_t` type not `int`:

```
const char *name;
size_t size;
```

---

Further after using `avro_generic_value_new` you have to deallocate space after usage by:

```
avro_generic_value_free(&frame_value);
```

Also you have to use:

```
avro_value_iface_decref(frame_iface);
avro_schema_decref(frame_schema);
```

as the API does reference counting, it's necessary to free the space after usage.

---

Moreover I would recommend to always check the return values of the functions, they are `int` or a pointer and the meaning is explained by the [API documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/c/):

> Most functions in the Avro C library return a single `int` status code. Following the POSIX `errno.h` convention, a status code of `0` indicates success. Non-zero codes indiciate an error condition. Some functions return a pointer value instead of an `int` status code; for these functions, a `NULL` pointer indicates an error.
>
> You can retrieve a string description of the most recent error using the `avro_strerror` function:
>
> ```
> avro_schema_t  schema = avro_schema_string();
> if (schema == NULL) {
>    fprintf(stderr, "Error was %s\n", avro_strerror());
> }
> ```

Comment: it quits with segmentation fault.Debugged with gdb name has some junk value 
(gdb) p name
$2 = 0x100000000 "\317", <incomplete sequence \372\355\376\007>

Comment: Hi @sanyamjain if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.